# Getting property of non-object in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created this snippet of PHP code with WordPress but I get this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
```

My code:

```
<?php global $post; $author_id=$post->post_author; ?>

<?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $author_id ) ) { ?>
            <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta( 'twitter', $author_id ); ?>" title="Följ @<?php the_author_meta( 'twitter', $author_id ); ?> på Twitter" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire error message?

Comment: @LorenzoZottar It just refering to the code, the first line above.

Comment: What happen if you make a var_dump of $post?

Answer (score 3):

That is because in the first interaction `$post` is not a object yet. maybe I am wrong since I can't see the rest of the code, but this will solve the issue:

```
 <?php 
   global $post; 
   if(is_object($post)):

       if ( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', the_author_meta('ID')) ): ?>
              <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta( 'twitter', the_author_meta('ID')); ?>" title="Följ @<?php the_author_meta( 'twitter', the_author_meta('ID')); ?> på Twitter" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
   <?php endif; 
    endif; ?>
```

Tested since I haven't tested in this scenario. You could also use `is_array()` for arrays

<del>EDIT: Just notice that you are tying to get the author ID, `the_author_ID()` is the correct way to do it.</del>

EDIT: Digging a bit more, you doing even need to do that. you have [get_author_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) which is a better solution for what you need

Comment: Not only is `the_author_ID()` deprecated...it's the wrong function to use in this case. You don't need to echo anything.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check it was deprecated i need to check the docs more often @mevius